# Using Git with IntelliJ and Maven

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea

If I wanted to use just the normal git via the command line and not the one in IntelliJ, what do I need to include in the version control so when I download it, I can get the Maven libraries without manually installing them?

Edit: There is no pom.xml file when the libraries are added to an IntelliJ project, so I was wondering what I need to include so Maven inside IntelliJ can download the libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; whether you use git from the command line or the fine IntelliJ integration doesn't have anything to do with IntelliJ or Maven. Are you having a specific issue?

Comment: git doesn't automatically download maven libraries, maven automatically downloads maven libraries.

Comment: I don't think IntelliJ is even relevant to the question. As @azurefrog said, Maven will download the libraries. You just need the [pom.xml file](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html).

Comment: If you want to use Maven then sure, you'd need a pom.

Comment: @DaveNewton I got the libraries from Maven via the Project Structure window in IntelliJ. Is that technically not using Maven?

Comment: Not if it used Maven, no.

Answer (score 0):

> what do I need to include in the version control so when I download it, I can get the Maven libraries without manually installing them?

[The `pom.xml` file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#What_is_a_POM) does this:

> Some of the configuration that can be specified in the POM are the project dependencies, the plugins or goals that can be executed, the build profiles, and so on. Other information such as the project version, description, developers, mailing lists and such can also be specified.

Running `mvn install` will cause Maven to download your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij will automatically understand the changes in the pom files and update libraries of course you should have pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If its a maven based project, you definitely need a pom.xml file like below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>testing</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>testing</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Once you have a pom.xml file, you can define dependencies like the JUnit dependency defined above with the version you need and maven will automatically take care of downloading the dependency for the project. Once you add any new dependency to the pom.xml, you can run "mvn clean install" from the directory where you have the pom.xml file so that it installs the new dependency.

Hope this helps.